# Matching strings with and without escape characters with RegEx

Tags: regex, powershell, split

I have different distinguished names from Active Directory objects and need to filter out escape characters when splitting those dn´s into simple names.

I already have a string `-split` of PowerShell in place, but this does not filter out escape characters. I´ve tried regex with a positive lookbehind but i do need in this case something like a optional positive lookbehind? Maybe I'm just thinking too complicated.

String examples:

1. `OU=External,OU=T1,OU=\+TE,DC=test,DC=dir`
2. `OU=\#External,OU=T1,OU=\+TE,DC=test,DC=dir`
3. `OU=\+External,OU=T1,OU=\+TE,DC=test,DC=dir`

Because `+` and `#` are escaped but are the actual name of those objects, I need to remove the escape characters

With following PowerShell it is possible to get the name of the object

```
($variable -split ',*..=')[1]
```

Actual Result:

1. `External`
2. `\#External`
3. `\+External`

Expected Result:

1. `External`
2. `#External`
3. `+External`

It is possible to use regex with `$variable -creplace "REGEX"` but I cant find a regex which fits all those cases.

My try was: `(?<=OU=\\).+?(?=,OU=)` but just matches if the `\` is there

I need this name for the object creation inside Active Directory.

Comment: You can use the `-Replace` operator to remove the \. `$OU -Replace "\\"`.

Comment: You could add the slash as optional in the split `-split ',?..=\\?'` similar to how you handle the comma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With minimal change you could just add the slash as optional in your current regex. You already do something similar with the leading comma

```
"OU=\#External,OU=T1,OU=\+TE,DC=test,DC=dir" -split ',?..=\\?'
```

You could take that farther if you were just going for the first section but that answers your basic question. There is likely other efficiencies to be made but probably not worth it.

Comment: Thanks Matt ! This is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

For extracting the first OU name from a DN while removing an optional leading backslash at the same time you can use a regular expression like this:

```
OU=\\?(.*?), *..=.*$
```

Demonstration:

```
$dn1 = 'OU=External,OU=T1,OU=\+TE,DC=test,DC=dir'
$dn2 = 'OU=\#External,OU=T1,OU=\+TE,DC=test,DC=dir'
$dn3 = 'OU=\+External,OU=T1,OU=\+TE,DC=test,DC=dir'

$dn1 -replace 'OU=\\?(.*?), *..=.*$', '$1'  # output: External
$dn2 -replace 'OU=\\?(.*?), *..=.*$', '$1'  # output: #External
$dn3 -replace 'OU=\\?(.*?), *..=.*$', '$1'  # output: +External
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! im fairly new to regex and please that so many people are willing to help!